# bootstrap panel not working

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm using bootstrap with angular, but the panels aren't working correctly. I can confirm the files are in the right spots.[files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9w99H.png)
This is what it looks like: [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7kcm.png)
I can use btn and btn-primary, but not panel. What could be causing this issue?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-body">
            Basic panel example
          </div>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-success">test</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 74, accepted):

If you are using Bootstrap 4 read this:

```
Panels, thumbnails, and wells
Dropped entirely for the new card component.

Panels
.panel to .card, now built with flexbox.
.panel-default removed and no replacement.
.panel-group removed and no replacement. .card-group is not a replacement, it is different.
.panel-heading to .card-header
.panel-title to .card-title. Depending on the desired look, you may also want to use heading elements or classes (e.g. <h3>, .h3) or bold elements or classes (e.g. <strong>, <b>, .font-weight-bold). Note that .card-title, while similarly named, produces a different look than .panel-title.
.panel-body to .card-body
.panel-footer to .card-footer
.panel-primary to .card-primary and .card-inverse (or use .bg-primary on .card-header)
.panel-success to .card-success and .card-inverse (or use .bg-success on .card-header)
.panel-info to .card-info and .card-inverse (or use .bg-info on .card-header)
.panel-warning to .card-warning and .card-inverse (or use .bg-warning on .card-header)
.panel-danger to .card-danger and .card-inverse (or use .bg-danger on .card-header)
```

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/#panels-thumbnails-and-wells

Comment: yeah that's my issue, I didn't know they made this change thanks!

Comment: Anyone create an addon to BS4 to bring them back?

Comment: @Jonathan i dont think so

Answer (score 15):

For Bootstrap 4, `panels` have been [dropped](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#panels) in favour of `cards`

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="card" style="width: 20rem;">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
    <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Anyone create an addon to BS4 to bring them back?

Comment: @Jonathan Why would you need an addon? Cards are the same thing

Comment: they look different to me

Comment: @AshleyBrown One reason for wanting an addon is because you have tons of pre-made code that uses panels that you want to cut and paste, and you don't want to have to spend time converting everything over. Another reason might be that someone wants to upgrade the site to Bootstrap 4 (perhaps change the theme), and you want the existing pages to continue working until they are updated.

Comment: Find and replace class names with CTRL/CMD + F globally

Comment: even though this answer is correct, the example given could not be worse.. its missing card header and they even force the width .. why ??

Comment: @Jaxx0rr OP's code example didn't include the header, so neither did I. The header isn't required, as you can mix and match which ever parts that you need. As for the width, I did that for the purposes of running this stackoverflow demo.

Comment: I know but poeple looking for answers need something that looks like the old bootstarp panel.. and a card with no width and a header actually does.. vs this example.. that does not.. and then people continue searching.. and that is.. bad...

Comment: @Jaxx0rr This was a question about something very specific about their code, and it's been specifically addressed. The header is irrelevant to the question thats being asked. They never asked for a fully featured conversion of the component. They simply asked why their code did not work.

This was never supposed to 'show' how to use a panel/card with a header. 

If you wish to ask a different question to OP's, (e.g. "How do I use the header in a Bootstrap card?") then feel free to create a new question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: yes, but can you maybe change your mindset when you answer questions from now on and maybe think of the literally thousands of people (like me) googling "bootstrap 5 panels" and ending up here just to try the example and be discouraged.. or am I asking too much of you ? have you ever used a panel ? who even uses a card without the header ? ok I get it you don't want to do it fine.. but stop arguing with me that it is unnecessary.. this is why we cannot have good things

Comment: No. Stackoverflow is a place to get help with a specific coding question. What you want is something that this question does NOT ask. If you want an answer that shows you a full example of a Boostrap panel/card then seek that question on Stackoverflow specifically. What's so hard to grasp about this? Oh and one other thing - this is for Bootstrap 4, so the very fact you're here in seek of knoweledge about Bootstrap 5 just goes to show you how this is not the page you want or need.

Answer (score 0):

**Hit**: ctrl+shift+i or Right click and choose inspect then click on console to make sure you dont have issue and The bootstrab JavaScript file is called 
and but that code in html file

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">Panel heading without title</div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    Panel content
  </div>
</div>

<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    Panel content
  </div>
</div>
```

but your bootstrap.js file at the end of body tag

Answer (score -2):

i suggest you add a all panel items, i think you should add panel-heading and panel-footer and in addition to a container.

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box">

        <div class="panel panel-default">
           <div class="panel-heading">
             <p>This a title</p>
           </div>
           <div class="panel-body">
              Basic panel example
           </div>
           <div class="panel-footer">
             <button class="btn btn-success">test</button>
           </div>   
       </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```